# Условная компиляция C++

Tags: c++, ооп, компиляция, cmake

Пытаюсь реализовать условную компиляцию на C++, проверяющую наличие строки add_subdirectory() и target_link_libraries() в cmake, но никак не получается. При добавлении строки add_subdirectory и target_link_libraries компилятор не видит условия и код не выполняется. Использую Visual Studio.

Код из `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
if(TARGET image_norm)
    add_definitions(-DENABLE_IMAGE_NORM)
    message("IMAGE_NORM ENABLE")
else()
    MESSAGE("IMAGE_NORM DISABLE")
endif()
```

Код из `.hpp`:

```cpp
#ifdef ENABLE_IMAGE_NORM
   #include <image_norm/image_norm.hpp>
#endif
```

Код из `.cpp`:

```cpp
#if defined (IMAGE_NORM)
                ImageNorm a;
                a.load_img(filePathName_copy);
                cv::Mat img = a.normalize();

                cv::imwrite("output.jpg", img);

                std::string filePathName_processed = "output.jpg";

                std::string file_name = obj.filePathName;
                const char* cstr_processed = filePathName_processed.c_str();

                bool ret_processed = ScanGui::LoadTextureFromFile(cstr_processed, &obj.my_image_texture_processed, &obj.my_image_width, &obj.my_image_height);
                IM_ASSERT(ret_processed);
#endif
```

Comment: Что не получается?

Comment: При добавлении строк add_subdirectory и target_linkLibraries, строчка #include <image_norm/image_norm.hpp> не подсвечивается, как должна была

Comment: Но я поменял код, подумал так будет выглядеть полегче. Вместо поиска строк по cmake файлу, просто проверяю на наличие таргета image_norm

Comment: Почему строка должна подсвечиваться? И где? Если вы работаете в какой-то среде разработки, которая работает не так как вы ожидаете, то опишите всю проблему целиком в вопросе.

Comment: Изменил вопрос, добавил больше конкретики

Comment: Используйте `target_compile_definitions(image_norm PRIVATE ENABLE_IMAGE_NORM)`.

Comment: Воспользовался вашим советом, все получилось, условная компиляция работает